# AMCL and gmapping combination problem

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to work with ROS , In my robot model I used both gmapping and AMCL , But when using both AMCL particlecloud did not coincide and there was a huge gap between base_footprint and particlecloud therefore AMCL become useless by this way. Next I start to tune parameters in AMCL to gain good results for this problem and in the meantime I run my robot without AMCL only using gmapping for localization. The observations are hopeful and it worked well. My question is are we really need both AMCL and gmapping for robot navigation and is it has huge advantage if we used both in our navigation stack ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326880/amcl-and-gmapping-combination-problem/) by [Yasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/43453/yasitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gmapping (or Cartographer) is used when you do NOT have an existing map and you need to do SLAM - Simultaneous Localization and Mapping.  It builds a map as it goes and publishes the pose relative to that map.

AMCL is used when you already have an existing map, and you want to calculate your pose relative to this existing map.

Using both in the same area is not typical.  One could imagine  using AMCL for a known area, and then switching to Gmapping, but not both at the same time.  With both running you would have a situation where both systems are trying to publish the base link to map transform, and you will get poor likely oscillating behavior.

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) with karma: 476 on 2019-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/43453/yasitha/) on 2019-06-26**:
Thank you for the answer I got good understanding about it now with help of your answer.